# PlayFrameWork: passing variables to a tag call

Tags: playframework

is it somehow possible to pass variables to a tag call:

I mean something like this:

```
#{plotGraph 
                    name:'${name}',
                    yAxis:'mA',
                    [...] 
/}
```

I get following error:

```
... does not compile : #{plotGraph} is not closed.
```

Answer (score 3):

My immediate remark without thinking and reading your real problem: If you just use the variable name itself, doesn't it work?

```
#{plotGraph 
                    name:name,
                    yAxis:'mA',
                    [...] 
/}
```

Comment: Thanks it works.
How could I have missed only the most obvious combination :(, but I'm still new to this groovy stuff..

Comment: I certainly did the same thing when I began Play! so you're not alone :)